# The dual group of $\mathbb Q$

Tags: harmonic-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis

What is the dual group of the additive group of rational numbers equipped with the standard topology inherited from $\mathbb R$? As a group, this dual group is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ (see the answer of Ekedahl given below), but it should be equipped with the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets of $\mathbb Q$. What are the properties of this group? Is it locally compact? what are its connected components? does it have more natural structure?

Comment: Something very interesting is the compact group obtained as the dual of $\mathbb{Q}$ with the discrete topology!


Comment: Note that there is also a $p$-adic analogue of this question, for which the answer is also the analogous thing (i.e., replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{Q}_p$ in every instance).  

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, uniform convergence on compact subsets of $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$ induces the usual topology on its group of (continuous) characters $\mathbb{R}\simeq\{t\mapsto\exp(ixt)\}_{x\in\mathbb{R}}$.

Namely, consider $K=\{0\}\cup\{1/n,n\geq 1\}$. For $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the corresponding character is uniformly $\epsilon$-close on $K$ to the trivial character iff $$|exp(ix/n)−1|<\epsilon\;\;\;\; (*)$$ for all integers $n\geq1$. Then for $\epsilon<1/\sqrt{2}$, $x$  must be small : $|x|<2\epsilon/\pi$. Indeed, consider $k\in\mathbb{Z}$  such that $|x−k\pi|\leq\pi/2$ , and take $n=|k|$; if $k\neq 0$ we reach a contradiction in $(*)$. Hence $k=0$, and the claim follows easily.

This implies that uniform convergence on compact subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ (in fact the one compact subset $K$) induces the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}\simeq\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Q},S^1)$.

Answer (score 13):

Every continuous group homomorphism $\mathbb Q \rightarrow S^1$ extends to the
completion of $\mathbb Q$ (cf., Bourbaki: General topology, Prop. III:4.8) which
is $\mathbb R$ so the dual group of $\mathbb Q$ is the same as that of $\mathbb
R$ which is $\mathbb R$. (There may be some question as to whether the
topologies are the same but I am not even sure which topology to use for the
dual group when the group is not locally compact.)

**Addendum**: Erased previous addendum as it was all wrong.

Comment: A continuous group homomorphism is of course uniformly continuous, thus extends to the completions.


Comment: Which is the argument of my reference (chosen because it is where uniformities are introduced)...

Comment: Compact subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ are finite. So uniform convergence on compact subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ ist the same as convergence in all rational points.

Comment: @Johannes : $\mathbb{Q}$ has infinite compact subsets, like a sequence converging to a rational and its limit.

Comment: @Johannes: Is that already an answer in the "common misconceptions" question?  If not it should be.


Comment: This is an artifact of the difference between the discrete topology and the induced topology of $\mathbb{Q}.$ A Hausdorff topological space is discrete if and only if the only compact subsets are finite.

Comment: It is easy to see that if $x$ is real and $|\exp(ix/n)-1|<\epsilon$   for all integers $n\geq1$, then for  small enough $\epsilon$ ($\epsilon<1/\sqrt{2}$  should work), $x$ must be small : $|x|<2\epsilon/\pi$ (hint: consider $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $|x-k\pi|\leq \pi/2$, and take $n=|k|$ if $k\neq 0$). This implies that uniform convergence on compact subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ (in fact one compact subset) induces the standard topology on `$\mathbb{R}\simeq\{t\mapsto\exp(ixt)\}_{x\in\mathbb{R}}$`.

Comment: @Victor: *A Hausdorff topological space is discrete if and only if the only compact subsets are finite.* I don't believe it.  First-countable, OK, but in general for Hausdorff?


Comment: @Victor: Consider $X={\mathbb R}\cup\{\infty\}$ with the topology consisting of the discrete topology on $\mathbb R$ and with a base of neighborhoods at $\infty$ consisting of intervals $]k,\infty]$ with $k\in{\mathbb N}$. Compact sets in this space are finite, but the space is not discrete.

Comment: @Hany: In your topology, $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ is compact, right? How about the base of neighborhoods of $\infty$  consists of the co-countable subsets?